# Having different profiles for different kind of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, devise, rolify

I have a web-app page where I have a teacher and a student.

When they sign up via devise they get redirected to a welcome page that asks them to identify as either a student or teacher and get assigned that role via the rolify gem. Once they click one of the options I want the user redirected to their profile/edit page. However I need the profile edit page for teacher and student to be different necessarily since I need their profile pages to be different. They will have different kind of information to fill out.

What is the best way to do this? I already have a users model and rolify roles for each but I am not understanding how I can have different information for each user role. There must be different views although they are both users so its confusing.

Am i supposed to create two new models one for each that inherit from user? Am I supposed to use something like pundit instead of rolify? I'm pretty new to rails would appreciate the help thanks.

User should be able to later change what kind of user they are.(important edit)

Comment: I'm new also and have no experience building something like this. However I would give your `user` a `isTeacher` and `isStudent` attribute. Also I would set up student-only and teacher-only tables to store relevant data. Relate the `student/teacher` to the `user` db records simply with `user-id` and it's also easy to toggle and switch the state of the `user`

Comment: Its very difficult to answer "supposed to" questions, especially ones as broad as this. Its very much up to you and the requirements of your project whether to create separate models or one model. Can you generalize the differences sufficiently to use the same model? or are the differences significant enough to warrant separate models? I can only restate the question for you. If there are particular differences you're worried about, please ask about those: its much easier to answer concrete questions, especially with some code already written.

Comment: I will say that if you choose separate models, you can abstract shared code into a module.